# Позиции вхождения второй строки в первую

Tags: строки, c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   char str[100];
   char substr[50];
   int i;
   printf("Vvedi stroku:"); gets(str);
   printf("Vvedi podstroku:"); gets(substr);   
   char* p;
   p=strstr(str, substr);
   printf("Pozicii vhozhdeniya: %s\n", p);
   i=0;
   while (p=strstr(p,substr)) 
   {
      i++; p++;
   }
   printf("Vsego Vhozhdenii: %d\n", i);

    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Необходимо, чтобы программа распечатывала позиции вхождения второй строки в первую и их общее количество. У меня программа считает вхождением только 2 одинаковых строки и не определяет позиции вхождения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить?

Comment: Видимо внимательно прочесть `man strstr` и если что-то останется непонятно, то вернуться к главе об указателях и адресной арифметике в книжке по Си (или С++).

Comment: <pre>int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char str[100], substr[50];
  printf("Vvedi stroku:"); gets(str);
  printf("Vvedi podstroku:"); gets(substr);   
  char* p;
  // c - счетчик вхождений.
  // i - индекс символа, начиная с которого ищем подстроку.
  for (int c = 1, i = 0; i < 100 && (p = strstr(&str[i], substr)); i++)
    printf("Poziciya vhozhdeniya #%d: %d\n", c++, i = p - str);
  _getch();
  return 0;}<code>
Попробовал такой вариант. Ввожу 1ую строку, 2ую строку. Программа результат не выводит. В чем может быть причина?